# Toolbar does not appear properly SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, toolbar, titlebar

In my GeneralView I have a NavigationView And a Tab View.
Inside each tabItem I navigate with some ZStack (using zIndex, hiding and showing items)

Randomly leading and trailing items are not shown properly and can't be clicked.
See below, on top of screen back button is not full. But I select same button to go on the "Coureur1View"
Info : I do not have any other problem with this navigation.

[image: pb]

In My generalView :

```
 .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .principal) {
                TitleBarView().environmentObject(objCourse)
            }}
        .navigationBarItems(leading: TitleBarLeadingView(), 
                          trailing: TitleBarTrailingView())
```

I don't have problem with TitleBarView (principale) but with leading and trailing
In my TitleBarLeadingView :

```
struct TitleBarLeadingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var objGroupe : GroupeActuel
    @EnvironmentObject var objCourse : CourseActuelle
    @EnvironmentObject var zindex : Zindex

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        if zindex.selectedTab > 0 {
             if zindex.detailCoureurVisible {
                Button{
                    zindex.detailCoureurVisible = false
                } label : {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                    Text("Back")
                }.foregroundColor(.orange)
                
            }else{
                EmptyView()
            }else{
                EmptyView()
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided snapshots are not testable, so just idea - try to recreate navigation bar items forcefully. It can be on some known changed value (I see titled changed on gif), but also can be just by UUID():

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: TitleBarLeadingView().id(UUID()), 
                  trailing: TitleBarTrailingView().id(UUID()))
```

*Note: make `.id(param)` is preferable because by UUID it will be recreated by each refresh.*